# Async getAccounts doesn't see my account

Tags: web3js, metamask, react

first time using MetaMask web3

Async getAccounts does not return my Eth account which I see in MetaMask.

My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ysz11/qcv78h9z/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Virtual data room</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Target container -->
  <div id="app"></div>

  <!-- React library and ReactDOM -->
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="web3.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel">

    // JSX code here. Or link to separate JavaScript file that contains JSX.

    const Web3Context = React.createContext(undefined);

    const App = () => {
      // TODO

      const web3 = React.useContext(Web3Context);

      const [accounts, setAccounts] = React.useState(["0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1"]);

      // cDM
      React.useEffect(() => {
        web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accs) => {
          if (err != null) {
            console.log(err)
          }

          console.log(accs);

          setAccounts(accs);
        });
      }, []);

      return (
        <div>
          <div>Ethereum js api version {web3.version.api}</div>

          {accounts.length} accounts:
          <ul>{accounts.map((acc, i) => (
              <li key={i}>{acc}</li>
          ))}</ul>
        </div>
      );
    }

    const AppNoMetaMask = () => {
      return (
        <div>Please install MetaMask</div>
      );
    }

    const HasMetaMask = () => {
      return (
        <div>{ (window.ethereum !== undefined) ?
                 <Web3Context.Provider value={new Web3(window.ethereum)}>
                   <App /> 
                 </Web3Context.Provider> :
                 <AppNoMetaMask /> }</div>
      );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <HasMetaMask />,
      document.getElementById("app")
    )

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is not a single `async` in your code!

Answer (score 1):

This was missing

```
     const HasMetaMask = () => {
+
+      // cDM
+      React.useEffect(() => {
+        window.ethereum.enable().then((account) => {
+          const defaultAccount = account[0];
+          web3.eth.defaultAccount = defaultAccount;
+
+          // done
+        });
+      }, []); // once
+
       return (
```

https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8